# How to filter NA values in columns of pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a datatable as,

```
DT_EX= dt.Frame({
               'country':['a','a','a','a'],
               'id':[3,3,3,3],
               'shop':['dmart','dmart','dmart','dmart'],
               'beef':[23,None,None,None],
               'eggs':[None,33,None,None],
               'fork':[None,None,10,None],
               'veg':[None,None,None,40]})
```

It's output is as,

[image]

And I would like to convert it to a datatable which should not have NA's in columns as showed in this output,

[image]

Could you please explain how to do this operation(removing NA's) on py-datatable?. would dt.isna() be helpful in this case?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around it would be to select the first three columns (they have no nulls) and extend it with the sum of the remaining columns : [link](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/f-expressions.html#modifying-a-columnset)

```
from datatable import f, first, sum

DT_EX[:,first(f[:3]).extend(sum(f[3:]))]

    country id  shop    beef    eggs    fork    veg
▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪
0   a   3   dmart   23  33  10  40
```

UPDATE: simpler solution from another related question:

```
DT_EX[:, sum(f[3:]), f[:3])]
```

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy looks like you are using pydatatable in COLAB notebooks, when you execute the code chunk does it display two output formats of datatable ?. or single one?. for me it's giving two format. i think in youe above mentioned output it's a singe output format. can you please tell me how you did it.

Comment: it gives me a single format. i use jupyter notebooks

Comment: Oh ok, it's giving me a single output in Jupyter notebooks as well. but when it comes to colab notebook it prints two outputs, can you try it once?.

Comment: i rarely use colab. when i've got some time on me, i'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

So i have one more subgroup of items and here is a new DT.

```
DT_EX= dt.Frame({
'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c'],
'id':[3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
'shop':['dmart','dmart','dmart','dmart','amzn','amzn','amzn','amzn'],
'beef':[23,None,None,None,93,None,None,None],
'eggs':[None,33,None,None,None,103,None,None],
'fork':[None,None,10,None,None,None,210,None],
'veg':[None,None,None,40,None,None,None,340]})
```

I have tried to appply the recommended logics on it as here in the attached screenshot,

[image]

In second code chunk it has summed up each column(beef,eggs,fork,veg)

and In the third code chunk, i did a grouping on first three columns, here it gives a correct output, but it's adding duplicate columns, and another observation is that its filling NA values with 0, it can be found on C observation.

would you have any other ideas/suggestions for it ?.

Comment: Hi, can u set this up as a new question. This also allows other people to see it and attempt as well. I’ll give it a shot once I am on my PC

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: I just posted this as a new question on SO.